# Recovering ContactResults for deformable body?

Tags: drake

I am interested in recovering the ContactResults object for a deformable body interacting with rigid elements in the world, such as the `deformable_torus.cc` example.

I added the following to `deformable_torus.cc`:

```
auto contact_info = plant.get_contact_results_output_port().Eval<drake::multibody::ContactResults<double>>(plant_context);
```

This works for recovering the ContactResults for other examples (e.g., worked well for recovering contact information for `inclined_plane_with_body.cc`), but here yields the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  MultibodyPlant received contact results for GeometryId 37, but that ID is not known to this plant
```

Is there a way to recover the ContactResults when interacting with a deformable body?

Comment: Querying contact results for deformable bodies is not supported at the moment. However, we should at least throw a less obscure message. If you elaborate on what information you are hoping to retrieve about the deformable contact information, it could help shape how we support the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the loop here: The feature has been added in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/20274. You should be able to use it if you build from source or use the nightly release. Otherwise, it will be available in the next stable release v1.23.0.